# Webpack Hashing *after* uglification

Tags: javascript, webpack

We're using the `style-loader` in webpack, which, when compiled seems to place information about the current directory in the source code that injects style tags when modules are loaded/unloaded. It looks roughly like this:

```
if(false) {
    // When the styles change, update the <style> tags
    if(!content.locals) {
        module.hot.accept("!!./../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./../../../../../node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity/node_modules/node-neat/node_modules/node-bourbon/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity/node_modules/node-neat/node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/infl-fonts!./campaigns.scss", function() {
            var newContent = require("!!./../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./../../../../../node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity/node_modules/node-neat/node_modules/node-bourbon/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity/node_modules/node-neat/node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/patternity&includePaths[]=/var/deploy/referrals/web_head/releases/20151118202441/node_modules/infl-fonts!./campaigns.scss");
            if(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
            update(newContent);
        });
    }
    // When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags
    module.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });
}
```

The thing to note is the directory listed in the `accept` string.

Now, this code ultimately gets removed once uglify is run (because of the `if (false)`) which is great. Where my problem lies however is that this compilation happens on 2 machines and the chunk hashing appears to happen *before* uglification, because the hash generated on 2 different machines (or even on the same machine but when in a different folder) is different. This obviously won't work if I'm deploying to, say, a production machine and need both of these machines to serve up an asset with the same digest.

Just to clarify, when not minified, the code is different, thus generates a different hash, but minification *does* in fact make the files identical, however the chunk hashing appears to have happened before minification.

Does anyone know how I can get the chunkhash to be generated *after* the uglify plugin is run. I'm using a config like so:

```
...
output: {
  filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
...
```

with the command:

```
webpack -p
```

**edit**

So after looking over this. I'm seeing now that this has to do with us adding `includePaths` to our style loader, it looks like this:

```
var includePaths = require('node-neat').includePaths;
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass?includePaths[]=" + includePaths },
  ]
}
```

So I think we know *why* we're getting these absolute URLs, but I think the original question still stands, IMO webpack should be hashing chunks AFTER minification, not before.